# which trigger event Before update or After update needs to be used for below scenario?

Tags: trigger

if an account is updated,all its contacts should be updated. which trigger event we need to use? since both before and after update has trigger.newMap

Comment: typically, updating related recs is done in afterUpdate

Comment: yes, usually you change records itself in `before` context and update related records and some other non-related staff in `after` context.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply search `Apex Triggers`, you will find this documentation useful [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm):

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.

Specifically, **after triggers are used to affect changes in other records**. The above passage is also included in the [Get Started with Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro#:%7E:text=Before%20triggers%20are%20used%20to,after%20trigger%20are%20read%2Donly.) Trailhead module.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you change records itself in `before` context and update related records and some other non-related staff in `after` context.

Therefore, for your scenario, I would recommend using `after update`.

Strictly speaking, there is no difference for your case, but it's just a good conversion to follow

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: your welcome, if this answers your question, please accept it.